# Ошибки при компиляции через Unity

Tags: unity3d

при компиляции выходят эти ошибки:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe -classpath
> "D:\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar"
> org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
> "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[ Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\Projkecıt\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']
> > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to
> > a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details.
> > This warning can be disabled by adding the line
> > 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the
> > project directory.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s ] stdout[ Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible
> Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details ] exit code: 1
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
> (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
> UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> :0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
> (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
> UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> :0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
> (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
> UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
> waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args,
> System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
> :0) Rethrow as
> GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
> UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
> (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
> workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> :0) Rethrow as BuildFailedException:
> Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild
> (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData,
> System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String
> installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName,
> UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
> usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
> target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName,
> System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height,
> UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
> usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> <97ba64834c8f4edc84e3d8e30b04f122>:0)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors   at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
> (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in
> <97ba64834c8f4edc84e3d8e30b04f122>:0    at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
> askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
> [0x00080] in <97ba64834c8f4edc84e3d8e30b04f122>:0
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused,
> use --status for details
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\Projkecıt\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']
> > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to
> > a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details.
> > This warning can be disabled by adding the line
> > 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the
> > project directory.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused,
> use --status for details
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle ругается на то, что у вас в пути к проекту

> D:\Projkecıt\

есть не Ascii символ - латинская i. При работе в юнити, чтобы избежать проблем путь должен состоять только из английских букв без пробелов, иначе могут начаться подобные проблемы.